# Dynamic Form depend on service I inject to component in angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, dependency-injection, angular-material

Is any option to make dynamic form in component depends on my injected service? Now i have specific route for my component. route-first is form MyComponent and inject firstService and route-second is MyComponent too and inject SecondService but now i want dynamic change form on this component depend on which service is injected. Can u help me?

Comment: How do you inject a different service in 2 different instances of the same component ? Can you show your code ?

Comment: It is base on route. Here is a link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-service-injection-tokens?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy%2Fmy.component.ts

Comment: So, can't you simply add a boolean, or something in your service (or maybe check its constructor name, something like that), to know which service is injected ?

Comment: Ok it is only 2 option. I want make something like 10 option and want have 1 compoennt which inject specifed service and depend on this service i generate specyfic form in this component. It is possible ?

Comment: and I know what service is but i want change form in component dynamicly depend on which service is injected

Comment: Well, you have to decide what abstraction you wish to have. You have 2 choices: Add booleans to your services, which will tell to your component which controls to add to your form. Or your component will decide which control to add/remove to the formGroup depending of the service name (so a kind of switch/case).

Comment: Initially create the formGroup with common fields of both services and when the service changes add or remove the control of the formGroup. Loop through the controls of formGroup in the template otherwise make an array of fields and loop through that array

Answer (score 0):

Take the following site as reference

[For Creating Dynamic Form](https://medium.com/@krishnaregmi/how-to-create-dynamic-forms-in-angular-7-using-formcontrol-a443a2c5e3a9)

I made some changes in your stackblitz demo

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-service-injection-tokens-yohrqd-rc5qg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy%2Fmy.component.html)